# Rails - Display Form inline

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having trouble displaying a Rails form in a horizontal line.

I have a view, it contains a table, w/ in a table cell I render a partial containing the form I want to be inlined:

View:

```
  <tr>
    <td>
        <%= @user.name %>           
    </td>   
    <td>
        <a href="#">Add Item</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= render :partial => '/items/new_item' %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Partial (Form):

```
<%= form_for( Item.new ) do |f| %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.text_field :content %>
        </div>
        <div class="action">
            <%= f.submit "Add Item", :class => 'item_submit' %>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

I have tried:

```
form{
    display:inline;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

And also creating a Unordered list w/in the form, and making the text field and submit button list items, then in the css making the list inline.  This didn't work either.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you could try to use span instead of div, or set display:inline for div, not for form.

Comment: Thanks. I was majorly overthinking that one.

Answer (score 0):

You could always float the divs in the form I.e.

form > div { float:left: display:inline-block;}

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<%= form_tag some_controller_path, method: 'POST', class: 'form-inline', style: 'display:inline !important;' do %>
```

... your form code here

```
<% end %>
```